# How to create a Blob from a Google Cloud Storage URL in Python

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a blob created using the google cloud storage API, and have saved its path using blob.path. The path is of the form

/b/bucketname/o/some%2Fobject%2Fid

How do I recreate the blob from this URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unfortunate that the GCS API doesn't provide a factory method to go from the path URL back to a blob, since saving blob paths in databases etc. is quite common.

Here is a factory method that allows you to go from a blob.path back to a blob:

```
def blob_from_blobpath(blob_path):
  import google.cloud.storage as gcs
  blob_path = blob_path[3:] # /b/
  slash_loc = blob_path.index('/')
  bucket_name = blob_path[:slash_loc]
  blob_name = blob_path[(slash_loc+3):] # /o/
  bucket = gcs.Client().get_bucket(bucket_name)
  return bucket.blob(blob_name)
```